# MediaWiki plugin for dynamic content via forms

Tags: forms, mediawiki, template

Are there any plugins for MediaWiki that would allow me to create a page that has a form at the top that when filled in populates tags further down in the document? Say someone would put a form with "Source Server:" and "Destination Server:" fields at the top. Once those were typed in it would automatically populate those names into the content lower so that when following the instructions you could just read the docs and not have to mentally replace things, and possibly mess it all up.

I'm not looking to make pages that are permanent, just ones that can have values entered before they are followed. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have the question quite clear so far, it may be just me, but do you think you can make it more clear?

Comment: As an example: top of the page I would have a text box with the label "Server Name". Once I enter text into that box it would then populate the instructions that are further down in the wiki page with the text from the box as appropriate, without actually modifying the page or refreshing(if possible).

Comment: So you are looking for a "mad libs" type of thing.  The text has blanks in it and you want the user to be able to enter the words at the top to fill in the text of the blanks?   I've never seen any site that has this.  I highly doubt that anybody has written a plugin for your specific CMS that does that.

Comment: I wish there was such a plugin, alas I do not think there is.